# Is beer belly a myth or fact?

Tags: beer

Will not stop the pints either way, but does beer really causes 'beer belly'?

Please provide links/research.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with homebrewing really? downvoted.

Comment: @brewchez I think this fit on the 'beer appreciation' category, as described in the faq. Granted, it doesn't have to do with brewing, but it is relevant if you are going to drink the beer you brew, just like questions on how to calculate the nutrition facts.

Answer (score 4):

It's to do with hormones, and not specifically beer but the fact that it's high in carbohydrates. As the blood sugar increases, the body produces more insulin to push the blood sugar into the cells and thus decrease the overall blood sugar level. But elevated insulin levels in men cases testosterone to be converted into estrogens, which is the cause of the beer belly (and sometimes accompanying man-boobs.) Testosterone is also converted into DHT, which is linked with prostate cancer and hair loss.

Source

- http://totalhealthmagazine.com/articles/obesity/belly-fat.html

Comment: It's not evidence or data, but by experimenting on myself I've found that eliminating foods whose bulk of calories comes from simple sugars is as effective at weight loss as removing beer from my diet entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Beer is an energy dense food, and if you take more energy in than your body metabolizes out you'll gain weight. If your body uses more energy than you take in, on the other hand, you'll lose weight.

I've seen arguments made that there is something very particular about beer that causes me to develop fat around the midsection, but the science is usually relatively soft. The much simpler explanation is just: beer = calories, excess calories = weight gain. Because beer doesn't always feel like a hunger-bound food in the way that, say, a cheeseburger does, however, it's sometimes easier to pick up piles of unexpected calories from beer than other sources.

Comment: The idea that obesity is the result of excess caloric intake is not well supported. See [here](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/25/4/390.full.pdf) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021968185901146)

Comment: I'm not sure what I should be looking for in these articles. All they seem to argue is that correlations are weak between body weight and gross food intake across individuals. There are, of course, many factors that influence a given individuals basal metabolic rate, but it is uncontroversial that changes in body weight for any given individual are driven by surpluses and deficits of energy intake relative to energy use.

Comment: This is starting to look like a thread hijack. But we're not too far from agreement. The thing is this: the human body is not a simple thermodynamic system. The role of hormones, and the effects on hormone production of what we eat, cannot be ignored. Calories from different source, fat, carbohydrate, protein, alcohol, have different hormonal effects on our bodies.